# Remove all lines with a blank line either side of it

Tags: regex, text

I don't need to use a particular language/program, as long as I can run it on Linux but, this is what I have:

```
TITLE1 - this is my title with some text next to it

Thing1        1        Thing2        2
Thing3        3        Thing4        4

TITLE2 - this is my title with some text next to it

Thing5        5        Thing6        6
Thing3        3        Thing7        7
```

And I want to remove all lines that have a blank line either side so the result would be something like this:

```
Thing1        1        Thing2        2
Thing3        3        Thing4        4
Thing5        5        Thing6        6
Thing3        3        Thing7        7
```

**Edit #1**

1. There is a blank line above TITLE1 but I'm not sure how to show it using indentation, nevertheless, inserting a blank line at the top is quite simple.
2. I did not write this structure, it has been provided to me as input, and it has thousands of entries.
3. The "TITLE" does not actually contain the word "TITLE"; the "Things" do not actually contain the word "Thing".

Comment: The line `Thing1` has a blank line above it and it's in the final output.  How do you rationalize this?

Comment: @JaredPar, I was literally just asking the same question!

Comment: I think OP needs another way to denote the title lines.

Answer (score 0):

The desired result you've listed in the question is at odds with the subject. the `TITLE1` line has no blank line above it yet is not in the result text. The line starting with `Thing1` has a blank line above but not below it and is in the result text.

It seems like what you really want is to remove the `TITLE` lines and blank lines from the output. One way to accomplish this given the source text in the question:

```
egrep -v '^[A-Z]{2}' filename | egrep -v '^$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pfft.  All these people getting upset because there's an exception...that first line.  Of course you can do this, even taking the first line exception into account:

```
sed -rz 's/(^|\n*)[^\n]*\S[^\n]\n//g' input.txt | sed -rz 's/^\s*\n+//'
```

The second `sed` gets rid of a leading blank link, which is actually kind of difficult to eliminate otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The [awk version here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936327/remove-a-line-surrounded-by-blank-lines) works on your input.

```
awk '$2' ORS='\n' FS='\n' RS= input_file
```

---

In principle, this should be similar to some questions about [deleting sets of 2 or 3 blank lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598916/how-to-use-sed-to-remove-only-double-empty-lines), but the implementation below didn't work as intended (matched only the first title line, and deleted the last line of the file).  Any thoughts from people who read multiple lines into pattern space regularly?

```
$ sed '1N; N; s/^\n.*[a-z].*\n$/blargh/g ; P; D' input_file
blargh
Thing1        1        Thing2        2
Thing3        3        Thing4        4

TITLE2 - this is my title with some text next to it

Thing5        5        Thing6        6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in ruby:

```
s = """
TITLE1 - this is my title with some text next to it

Thing1        1        Thing2        2
Thing3        3        Thing4        4

TITLE2 - this is my title with some text next to it

Thing5        5        Thing6        6
Thing3        3        Thing7        7

TITLE1 - this is my title with some text next to it

Thing1        1        Thing2        2
Thing3        3        Thing4        4

TITLE2 - this is my title with some text next to it

Thing5        5        Thing6        6
Thing3        3        Thing7        7
"""
r = /^\n.*\S+.*\n^\n/
out = s.gsub(r, '')
print out
```

Here is a link to see this in action: http://rubular.com/r/uFl75LdAkS